# Is there a perfect group which is a finite extension of the discrete Heisenberg group $H_3(\Bbb Z)$?

Tags: gr.group-theory

We assume that $G$ is a finite extension of the [discrete Heisenberg group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group) $H_3(\Bbb Z)$, that is,
$$
1 \rightarrow H_3(\Bbb Z) \rightarrow G \rightarrow F \rightarrow 1
$$
where $F$ is a finite group.
Is it possible that $G$ is a perfect group?

This question is also posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2676714/is-there-a-perfect-group-which-is-a-finite-extension-of-the-discrete-heisenberg).

Comment: It was posted under a wrong tag (abstract-algebra); possibly it would have been answered there with the correct tag.

Comment: And it's now answered on MathSE (the answer is no).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s no longer relevant.